# How to find yield strength and Young Modulus from S-S curve

Tags: materials, material-science

I have a S-S curve and am not sure how to find yield strength from it as when I did 0.2% strain (0.002 * strain at fracture) I get a small number that plots close to (0,0)?

For young modulus, I am not sure where to take the values as it’s not a completely straight line?

Are there any other methods here please?

Comment: What you will need to do depends on the application and the underlying theoretical assumptions.  E.g., for the young's modulus you can compute tangent moduli at each point and take the average, or compute the secant modulus between two points.

Comment: I guess no one uses "drop of the beam" anymore.

Answer (score 1):

if the material is mild steel then the easiest way to find the yield stress is to plot the stress strain and find the first knee in the curve.

[image]

if the material does not have a clear yield point, what you do, is you start from 0.2% strain and draw a **straight line** parallel to the Elastic part of the line (see below).
The proof stress 0.2% (equivalent to yield stress) is the point where the straight line and the curve meet.

[image]

Regarding the Young's modulus, the best practice is to take two points from the proportional (elastic) range. See image below.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you NMech. Do I take 0.2% of the fracture strain please?

Comment: No. You just take 0.2% (absolute value).

Comment: Hi I think I see what to do, thank you! Youre too good

Comment: NMech, so can I call it just 0.2% of the x axis length then please?

Comment: It would be easier if you took a photo with the example and show what you tried to do, and updated the question. I am not sure what you mean by "*so can I call it just 0.2% of the x axis length*"

Comment: Hi, sorry I meant so 0.2% of every x axis value? And thank you a lot NMech

Comment: Still not sure what you mean. I'll try to explain with an example. If you have an original specimen length of 200[mm], then a displacement of 4[mm] will be equivalent to 0.2%. (see also this [question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/42311/why-is-the-stress-vs-strain-diagram-preferable-to-the-load-vs-displacement-diagr/42313#42313) on the similiarities and differences of stress strain  and load displacement curves)

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t sure myself. So I work out 0.2% original length then plot this strain please? And thank you

Comment: API makes it simpler to get steel yield ; go to 0.5 % strain , then go vertical to the test curve , the yield is load of the intersection point.  No slopes, no offsets. ( It is nearly the same result).

Comment: In Fig 1 , what is labeled "yield strength" is actually yield point.

Comment: You shall plot the S-S curve from the origin, at which both the stress and strain are zero. Then gradually increase the stress and measure the deformation, the corresponding strain is the deformation divide by the original length of the specimen.  Once you have enough data points, you can connect the dots and noticing there is a region connected by a straight line, within which, the deformation will recover once the stress is removed, it is so-called elastic range. Now you draw a line parallel to that straight line starting from a point with X measurement (strain) = 0.002 , and Y (stress) = 0.

Comment: Extend the line to intercept the S-S curve, the interception point is the nominal yield stress corresponding to 0.2% strain, and E = raise(stress)/run(strain). The fracture occurs long after the yield point and the ultimate point (peak strength) on the curve and representing absoluate failure.